# $product->get_name() возвращает NULL в Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Выскочила вот такая проблема. Если выключить WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing, все страницы отображаются нормально.

После недолгих поисков нашёл, что причина в том, что если продукт попадает под условие, прописанное в WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing, в переменной $product почему-то значение NULL.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_name() on null in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-shipping-method.php:277 Stack trace: #0 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shipping/legacy-local-pickup/class-wc-shipping-legacy-local-pickup.php(79): WC_Shipping_Method->add_rate(Array) #1 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-shipping-method.php(205): WC_Shipping_Legacy_Local_Pickup->calculate_shipping(Array) #2 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping.php(362): WC_Shipping_Method->get_rates_for_package(Array) #3 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-shipping.php(251): WC_Shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package(Array, 0) #4 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php(1444): WC_Shipping->calculat in /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-shipping-method.php on line 277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic Pricing - штука сильно платная. Зная наши реалии, скорее всего, "скачанная". Скорее всего, разъехались версии Dynamic Pricing и самого плагина WooCommerce, который в недавно появившейся 3 версии получил очень много изменений.